# A basic property of maximal correlation

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, it.information-theory

Let $$ and $$ be random variables. Then the maximal correlation $\rho_{m}(X;Y)$ is defined as:

$$\rho_{m}(X;Y):=\max_{f,g}\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)],$$

where the maximization is taken over real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ such that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[f^2(X)]=\mathbb{E}[g^2(Y)]=1$.

A single-function characterization of maximal correlation correlation was given by Rényi as follows:

$$\rho_{m}^2(X;Y):=\max_{f}\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[f(X)|Y])^2],$$ where $f$ satisfies the above conditions as well.

I'm interested to show that for any X,Y and Z random variables:
$$\rho_{m}((X,Z);Y) \ge \rho_{m}(X;Y)$$

How can we prove this basic definition ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your notation right, but isn't it just the observation that any function of $X$ can be considered as a function of $X,Z$?

Comment: I have re-edited the post by specifying that X, Y and Z are any random variables, thanks for your remark.
I see your point by comparing f(X) and f(X,Z), but in this case we will want $f(X,Z) \ge f(X)$. Notice that we can also invert the problem which is exactly the same:
 $$\rho_{m}(Y;(X,Z)) \ge \rho_{m}(Y;X)$$
So here we want to compare now :
$\max_{f}\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[f(Y)|X,Z])^2] \ge  \max_{f}\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[f(Y)|X])^2] $

Comment: I think this questions should be moved to MSE. (Hint: in your final formulation, just condition the integrand on the lhs with resp. to $X$ , and use Jensen's inequality for conditional expectations, before taking expectations.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment esg, I think this is exactly the good way to prove this. I just don’t understand exactly how to use the first condition that you mentioned with the $X$ on the lhs just before the Jensen inequality. You wanted to say: 
$max_{f}[([()|,])^2|]$ ?

Comment: No, I wanted to say: for any (admitted) $f$ we have (by Jensen's inequality) $\mathbb{E}\big[\big(\mathbb{E}(f(Y)|X,Z)\big)^2|X\big]\geq \big[\mathbb{E}(f(Y)|X,Z)|X\big]^2= \big[\mathbb{E}(f(Y)|X)\big]^2$ (a.s.), and thus $\mathbb{E}\big[\big(\mathbb{E}(f(Y)|X,Z)\big)^2]\geq \mathbb{E} \big[\big(\mathbb{E}(f(Y)|X)\big)^2\big]$. The rest is obvious.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification esg, it's clear for me now